# How can I wait until reducer store assignment is finished?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm using react-native with react-redux and redux-thunk. Basically I have a `Component` connected to `store` which modifies some information from it with `dispatch`. Despite every operation seems to be synchronous, I get old data on the next line after modification.

```
//reducer
import {assign as _assign} from 'lodash-es';
let initialState = {name: '1'};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'Project renamed':
            return _assign({}, state, {name: action.data});

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

//Component
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Prompt from 'react-native-prompt';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Prompt
                onSubmit={() => {
                    this.props.onProjectRenamed('2');
                    console.log(this.props.currentProject.name) //Still get '1' here!!!
                }}
            />;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currentProject: state.currentProject
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onProjectRenamed: (data) => dispatch({
        type: 'Project renamed',
        data: data
    })
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

How can I get new `this.props.currentProject.name` value?

Answer (score 3):

You can return a promise from your action and

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onProjectRenamed: (data) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'Project renamed',
            data: data
        })
        return Promise.resolve()
    }
});
```

Now you can use `then` on `onProjectRenamed`

```
onSubmit={() => {
    this.props.onProjectRenamed('2').then(() => console.log(this.props.currentProject.name))
}}
```

Comment: it works, but how? Everything in your `onProjectRenamed` seems to remain synchronous (`dispatch` first, returning `resolve` then). Why does `return Promise.resolve()` triggers only after `store` was modified?

Answer (score 1):

You are triggering an action when `onSubmit` is invoked. This action is updating state object, which means your component will receive new props.
If you implement, `ComponentWillReceiveProps` or `ComponentWillUpdate` methods of your component, and then try to print, `console.log(nextprops.currentProject.name)` inside it, you will get response as 2. simply try,

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { 
  console.log(nexProps.currentProject.name)
}
```

Remember when `render` method of your component is called after state has been updated, `this.props.currentProject.name` will have the latest value i.e. 2.

Refer to React Component [lifeCycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) for more detail.

Comment: Overriding `ComponentWillReceiveProps` works for me, but isn't there a way to pass callback or promise in `this.props.onProjectRenamed`?

Comment: I don't think so. If you can explain, why you want a callback, I might be able to suggest a solution for it.